# How can i find a running time of a recurrence relation?

Tags: recursion, big-o, complexity-theory

The running time for this recurrence relation is `O(nlogn)`. Since I am new to algorithm how would I show that mathematically?

```
T(n) = 2⋅T(n/2) + O(n)
T(n) = 2 ( 2⋅T(n/4) + O(n) ) + O(n)  // since T(n/2) = 2⋅T(n/4) + O(n)
```

So far I can see that if I suppose `n` to be a power of 2 like `n = 2m`, then may be I can show that, but I am not getting the clear picture. Can anyone help me?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the master theorem, you get the result you expected.

If you want to proof this "by hand", you can see this easily by supposing `n = 2m` is a power of 2 (as you already said). This leads you to

```
T(n) = 2⋅T(n/2) + O(n)
     = 2⋅(2⋅T(n/4) + O(n/2)) + O(n)
     = 4⋅T(n/4) + 2⋅O(n/2) + O(n)
     = 4⋅(2⋅T(n/8) + O(n/4)) + 2⋅O(n/2) + O(n)
     = Σk=1,...,m 2k⋅O(n/2k)
     = Σk=1,...,m O(n)
     = m⋅O(n)
```

Since `m = log₂(n)`, you can write this as `O(n log n)`.

At the end it doesn't matter if `n` is a power of 2 or not.
To see this, you can think about this: You have an input of `n` (which is not a power of 2) and you add more elements to the input until it contains `n' = 2m` Elements with `m ∈ ℕ` and `log(n) ≤ m ≤ log(n) + 1`, i.e. `n'` is the smalest power of 2 that is greater than `n`. Obviously `T(n) ≤ T(n')` holds and we know T(n') is in

```
O(n'⋅log(n')) = O(c⋅n⋅log(c⋅n)) = O(n⋅log(n) + n⋅log(c)) = O(n⋅log(n))
```

where `c` is a constant between `1` and `2`.

You can do the same with the greatest power of 2 that is smaller than `n`. This gives leads you to `T(n) ≥ T(n'')` and we know `T(n'')` is in

```
O(n''⋅log(n'')) = O(c⋅n⋅log(c⋅n)) = O(n⋅log(n))
```

where `c` is a constant between `1/2` and `1`.

In total you get, that the complexity of T(n) is bounded by the complexitys of `T(n'')` and `T(n')` wich are both `O(n⋅log(n))`and so `T(n)` is also in `O(n⋅log(n))`, even if it is not a power of 2.